# Python automatically generating variables

Tags: python, matplotlib

## Question

I have a question about Python creating new variables derived from other variables. I am struggling to understand how Python automatically knows how to generate variables even when I do not explicitly tell it to.

## Details

I am a new Python user, and am following along in the tutorials in: [Joel Grus, "Data Science From Scratch"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033400.do).

In the tutorial, I create three list variables:

1. `friends` contains the number of friends that someone has on a given
   social networking site
2. `minutes` refers to the number of minutes that they spend on the site
3. `labels` is simply an alphabetic label for each user.

Part of the tutorial is graphically plotting  labels next to the points when I create a scatterplot. In doing so, Python seems to automatically generate three new variables: `label`, `friend_count`, and `minute_count`.

In short - *how*? How does Python know to create these variables? And what do they do? They do not correspond to the mean, median, or mode of any of the lists.

## Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def make_chart_scatter_plot(plt):

    friends = [ 70, 65, 72, 63, 71, 64, 60, 64, 67]
    minutes = [175, 170, 205, 120, 220, 130, 105, 145, 190]
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

    plt.scatter(friends, minutes)

    # label each point
    for label, friend_count, minute_count in zip(labels, friends, minutes):
        plt.annotate(label,
                 xy=(friend_count, minute_count),
                 xytext=(5, -5), # but slightly offset
                 textcoords='offset points')

    plt.title("Daily Minutes vs. Number of Friends")
    plt.xlabel("# of friends")
    plt.ylabel("daily minutes spent on the site")
    plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: The 3 names are assigned the results of zip in the for loop

Comment: `friend` and the others are just names that **we** give python to refer to the object created on the right.  Python doesn't make it up, we tell it to use those names.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Thank you, everyone - I appreciate your quick responses. It sounds like I have a lot to learn about `for` and `zip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're actually creating the variables in the `for` loop:

```
for label, friend_count, minute_count in zip(labels, friends, minutes):
```

When you `zip` those together you're grouping them by the index, so the first item it iterates to is `(70, 175, 'a')`, the second is `(65, 175, 'b')`, and so on.  Python then *unpacks* those three results, because you ask it to assign to three variables, `label`, `friend_count` and `minute_count`.  If you were trying to unpack four variables and only supplied three names, for example, it would raise an error.

Then each time it iterates through the loop it reassigns the next values to those three variables.

Another way to think about this: if you wrote that line as:

```
for values in zip(labels, friends, minutes):
```

then `values` would just be the three items together every time, and those variables would not exist.  You could then unpack them within the loop if you wanted.  The way you posted is just a neater way to do it.

One more example of unpacking that you can play with yourself:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b, c, d = x
```

would assign `a=1`, `b=2` and so on.  However:

```
a, b = x
```

returns an error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 a, b = x
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

This gets more interesting using the `*` operator:

```
a, *b = x
```

results in:

> In [38]: a
>   Out[38]: 1
>
> In [39]: b
>   Out[39]: [2, 3, 4]

That is, the `*` tells Python that the last value is the place to dump whatever is left.  This behavior is again used a lot in functions, but can be used in for loops as well.  Actually note that this `*` operator only works with lists, as I illustrated above, in Python 3.x.  In 2.x you can still use it in functions this way, but not in assignment.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a prompt response! So, just to make sure I understand, the code is telling Python to unpack the `zip` into three containers that I have specified? Not trying to be dense, just want to make sure I get it :)

Comment: Yes, this is actually very standard in Python, and comes up for example when returning values from functions a lot.  I'll add another example to make it clear.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I am able to follow along right until I try to use `a, *b = x`, which for some reason gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: You're probably in Python 2.x then, it's a newer feature.

Comment: Ah - okay! Yes, I am using Python 2.7. Thank you very much for your help with everything!